# How to fix python-datamodel installation error? ValueError: 'datamodel/fields.pyx' doesn't match any files

Tags: python

Getting the following error, when running this line:

> pip install python-datamodel

```
Collecting python-datamodel
  Using cached python-datamodel-0.1.13.tar.gz (290 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Zheng Yao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Zheng Yao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Zheng Yao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Zheng Yao\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-xxrinum0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Zheng Yao\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-xxrinum0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 320, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Zheng Yao\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-xxrinum0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 154, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Zheng Yao\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-xxrinum0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 970, in cythonize
          module_list, module_metadata = create_extension_list(
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Zheng Yao\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-xxrinum0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 816, in create_extension_list
          for file in nonempty(sorted(extended_iglob(filepattern)), "'%s' doesn't match any files" % filepattern):
        File "C:\Users\Zheng Yao\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-xxrinum0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 114, in nonempty
          raise ValueError(error_msg)
      ValueError: 'datamodel/fields.pyx' doesn't match any files
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

My current version of python is Python 3.11.1, however according to https://pypi.org/project/python-datamodel/ the library supports python 3.8+. I'm using VSCode and running on Windows. How do I fix this error?